# explanation of retrograde development

Tags: vocabulary

> It is also applicable to a process (as of natural development) in which the events occur in an order contrary to the usual or progressive; thus. an animal that passes from a more complex to a simpler and often degenerate state during development is said to manifest retrograde development.

I would appreciate it very much, if somebody possibly throw a light on this explanation, maybe through another vivid example or simplification, as I am wondering about its concept.

Extracted from Merriam Webster

Answer (score 2):

*Retrograde* broadly means moving backward or becoming [worse than what it was](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/retrograde). Now, retrograde development becomes somewhat clear.

When we are talking in the context of an animal, retrograde development will be somewhat opposite to the natural development. It says *contrary to the usual or progressive event* which means it's not happen the way it naturally should.

Degeneration is a medical term which, in a layperson's language means, getting older i.e. declining in vitality or strength. When a living thing is in its development, degenerative changes are **not** expected. But as the paragraph reads, *..often degenerate state during development....* backs the meaning of 'retrograde development'.

In a very very simple language, 'retrograde development' in this context means the development happening in a way which is opposite to natural development.

Answer (score 0):

**Devolution**, [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/devolution), see Example Sentences of 1.1 and 1.3